# WCF service not running / or not recognized on IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service that is running fine on a few different servers, so I know there is no code issue with this.  Recently we put up a new Windows 2012 server in our dev environment.  I took the same deployment files and put them on the new server, created an application in IIS pointed to the folder with the files, but when I go to the URL all I get is what you see in the image below...  for other services on the same IIS I get the expected result which is the page that shows the WSDL etc...  Can someone tell me what I might be missing in my IIS setup?  It seems like IIS is not recognizing that this is a WCF application.

[image]

Comment: Did you run aspnet_regiis on the server?

Answer (score 13):

I think this happens when you do not have HTTP Activation checked in your windows features on the machine running IIS.

[image]

If that does not fix it or it was allready checked then the ISAPI filter for ASP.Net may be messed up. Run [aspnet_regiis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx) to re-register the ASP.NET filters on the website.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out that I needed to add a Handler in IIS.  If you click on the web site (in my case "Default Web Site") and the double click "Handler Mappings", then you can add a mapping for *.svc, like shown in the image:[image]